# Concatenate a float list with a string list from a table

Tags: python

I am trying to concatenate 2 columns from a table, column NAME with column ELEV.
One column in of type string and the other of type float.

It seems that when I convert the float column to string it concatenates all the entries inside the float column with one entry of the string column:

The code that I tried:

```
data=pandas.read_csv("Volcanoes.txt")
el=list(data["ELEV"])
data["INFO"]=data["NAME"]+", "+ str(el)+" m"
print(data["INFO"])
```

1st element in column INFO will result like this:
Baker, 0     3285.0\n1     3213.0\n2     4392....

I have tried iteration also:

```
for i in range(len(el)):
    data["INFO"]=data["NAME"]+", "+ str(el[i])+" m"
```

It creates the new column INFO with the NAME + last element in column ELEV.

Could you help me to concatenate one element from column NAME with corresponding entry from column ELEV

Comment: add some of the data in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). E.g.:

```
data["INFO"] = data["NAME"] + ", " + data["ELEV"].map(str)
```